# Можно ли делать PUSH-уведомления в приложениях на HTML5?

Tags: android, ios, html5

Можно ли делать PUSH-уведомления в приложениях на HTML5 под Android и iOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Смотря что вы называете приложением на HTML5, если просто страничку в браузере, то нельзя - пуши идут конкретному приложению через его идентификатор в системе (по крайней мере для iOS), а у странички такового, естественно, нет.

С другой стороны, есть возможность писать именно приложения с идентификаторами и всей обвязкой на HTML5 с помощью PhoneGap (можно и без него, был у меня такой опыт), когда приложение, по сути, представляет собой браузер и просто показывает ту же страничку, но поскольку у нас есть доступ к нативному коду, мы можем понавешать кучу всего, типа тех же пушей или ин-аппов.

Comment: Да, я имею ввиду именно приложение - второй описанный вами вариант.

Comment: Тогда в чем проблема? Там все стандартно, просто надо сделать какой-нибудь транслятор из нативного кода в js на страничке.

Answer (score 0):

Вроде бы да, я сам не пробывал, но доки видел, и в этом году добавился запрос сертификатов для веб-сайтов: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/NotificationProgrammingGuideForWebsites/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013225

Comment: Если верить их документации, оно только для мака работает, не для айоси - Note: This document pertains to OS X only. Notifications for websites do not appear on iOS.

Comment: Да, походу, это мак дев.